# SharePoint 2010 and ASHX Handler

Tags: 2010, development

I asked this on Overflow, but they thought I might get a better response here, so I'm repeating.

'm trying to get a webpart deployed and using a Silverlight webpart with an upload control inside. I am however, receiving the following error in the application log when I access my ashx.

Exception information: 
Exception type: HttpParseException 
Exception message: Could not create type 'FileUploadSP.UploadHandler'.

I've got an UploadHandler.cs file with the following code:

```
namespace FileUploadSP
{
public class UploadHandler : RadUploadHandler 
{
public override void ProcessStream()
{
    base.ProcessStream();

    if (this.IsFinalFileRequest())
    {
        string filename = this.Request.Form["RadUAG_fileName"];
        string fullPath = @"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\FileUploadSP\FileTemp\";
        SPContext.Current.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullPath + filename, FileMode.Open);
        SPContext.Current.Web.Files.Add("/UploadLibrary/" + filename, fs, true);
        fs.Close();
        File.Delete(fullPath + filename);
    }

}
}
```

And I have the following in my .ashx file:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Assembly Name="FileUploadSP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c8e2c3ef53023ee" %> 
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="FileUploadSP.UploadHandler" %>
```

I cannot get the .ashx to work as I expected to. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: what is RadUploadHandler, and is it also deployed ?

Answer (score 2):

a bet : the ashx requires the FQDN of the assembly. Try this :

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="FileUploadSP.UploadHandler, FileUploadSP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c8e2c3ef53023ee" %>
```

Comment: Nope, that last one didn't make a difference. The RadUpload thing is a silverlight control from Telerik. I'm wondering if I need to include the IHttpHandler there instead, but then the RadUpload wouldn't work. I will try that and remove the Telerik stuff just to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Ok, I was wrong, that seems to have taken care of the original error, but now I'm getting a new one.

Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpParseException 
    Exception message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpParseException' was thrown.